# Java language constructs to handle images

Tags: java, image-processing

I like to work out any project from scratch. These days, I have been assigned a template matching project that includes image handling besides other things to do. I plan to code the project in Java. Now I want a complete reference of the Java language constructs that are by one way or another related to image handling. I don't want to know about any third-party library but only the core Java ones. References based on Java SE 8 are preferred.

Comment: This forum is to help you with specific coding problems.  What are you having trouble with specifically? What have your tried? What is your issue?  This forum doesn't allow for question with no definitive answer.

Comment: Here is "a complete reference of the Java language constructs that are by one way or another related to image handling" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: For the beginners, this type of questions is common. Other than down-voting, the highly-reputed individuals of this forum should mention advice so that the newcomers may feel comfortable rather than discouraged.

Comment: What?  To your bad question, or all the thousands of bad questions that pour into SO every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start at [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) (links to Java SE 8 Docs).

A `BufferedImage` is exactly what it sounds to be like - an image buffer of RGB information. You can use `ImageIO` to deal with various file formats - no need to write code for PNG, BMP, JPG, or any other formats.

`ImageIO.read` loads an image from an image file, and `ImageIO.write` formats a `BufferedImage` object to whatever file format you want.